# Check if user has Facebook Messenger installed iOS 9

Tags: ios, facebook, ios9, messenger

Facebook has deprecated the method `[FBSDKMessengerSharer messengerPlatformCapabilities]`  that is used to check if the user has Messenger app installed. In the warning message, it says:

> messengerPlatformCapabilities is deprecated: This is deprecated as of iOS 9. If you use this, you must configure your plist as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

I would like to remove this method, but haven't found any other option to replace this code (that makes a button disabled if user hasn't Messenger app installed):

```
if (![FBSDKMessengerSharer messengerPlatformCapabilities]) {
    [self.inviteFriendsButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.inviteFriendsButton setAlpha:0.5f];
}
```

Is there any other method? Or, as new iOS requirements I should avoid using this `if`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will want to use `canOpenURL` to see if the Custom URL Scheme `fb-messenger://` can be opened. `canOpenURL` returns a `BOOL` value indicating whether or not the URL’s scheme can be handled by some app installed on the device. If `canOpenURL` returns `YES` then the application is present on the device.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb-messenger://"]]) {
    // Installed
    [self.inviteFriendsButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.inviteFriendsButton setAlpha:1.0];
}
else {
    // NOT Installed
    [self.inviteFriendsButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.inviteFriendsButton setAlpha:0.5];
}
```

Also, starting at iOS 9 you must include `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `info.plist`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the release of the Facebook SDK v4.6.0 they use `fb-messenger-api` as their URL scheme.

Swift 2.3

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb-messenger-api://")!) {
    // Installed
} else {
    // Not installed
}
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Swift 3**, use this:

```
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fb-messenger-api://")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to know whether to show a button users could press to share content on messenger.  This worked for my case, and it also checks whether the messenger app is installed.

```c
-(BOOL) canShareViaMessenger {
    [[[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init] canShow]
}
```